# Getting the sibling of an elementHandle in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm doing

```
const last = await page.$('.item:last-child')
```

Now I'd love to get the preceding element based on last. ie

```
const prev = last.$.prev()
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: is the await for the page load? You can also do `$(document).ready()` and then if you find your item with a jquery selector, you can just grab the prev() without needing any extra jQuery calls

Answer (score 20):

You should use [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) inside [`evaluateHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args), like this:

```
const prev = await page.evaluateHandle(el => el.previousElementSibling, last);
```

Here is full example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="item">item 1</div>
            <div class="item">item 2</div>
            <div class="item">item 3</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>`;

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

    const last = await page.$('.item:last-child');
    const prev = await page.evaluateHandle(el => el.previousElementSibling, last);

    console.log(await (await last.getProperty('innerHTML')).jsonValue()); // item 3
    console.log(await (await prev.getProperty('innerHTML')).jsonValue()); // item 2

    await browser.close();
})();
```