# How can I get HTML elements between two independent tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer. I have a situation where I need to get content between two tags which are not in a parent-child relationship.

```html
<h1>neverchangeA<h1>
<span>abc<span>
<span>abc2<span>
<h1>neverchangeB<h1>
```

Expected elements

```
<span>abc<span>
<span>abc2<span>
```

In simple, I need something like a regex similar to this:

```
regex.matchBetween(<h1>neverchangeA<h1>,<h1>neverchangeB<h1>)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the sibling of an elementHandle in Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861261/getting-the-sibling-of-an-elementhandle-in-puppeteer)

Comment: I am not sure, i need whatever elements between those two h1 elements, like regex

Comment: What are you going to do with the content between the tags? Do you just need the raw HTML or do you need puppeteer handle references to the elements?

Comment: Raw html content

Comment: Your example html is malformed because it is missing `/`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with JS and the evaluate method.

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args

This example returns the HTML of the desired elements as a string.

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const h1s = [...document.querySelectorAll('h1')]
  const neverChangeA = h1s.find(elem => elem.innerText === "neverchangeA")
  if(neverChangeA){
    const siblings = [...neverChangeA.parentNode.children]
    const indexOfFirstH1 = siblings.findIndex(elem => elem.innerText === "neverchangeA")
    const indexOfSecondH1 =  siblings.findIndex(elem => elem.innerText === "neverchangeB")
    const betweenELems = siblings.slice(indexOfFirstH1 + 1, indexOfSecondH1)
    const htmlOfElems = betweenELems.map(elem => elem.outerHTML)
    const result = htmlOfElems.join('')
    return Promise.resolve(result)
  }
  else {
    return Promise.resolve(null)
 }
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Getting the sibling of an elementHandle in Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861261/getting-the-sibling-of-an-elementhandle-in-puppeteer) explains how to get the previous sibling of an element with puppeteer. There is a similar function to get the next sibling of an element. You can apply this to your situation by writing a loop that starts with the first `<h1>` element then repeatedly gets the next sibling until you reach the second `<h1>` element.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution using XPath

This is a good use case for [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript). The following query looks for `span` elements that have an `h1` tag with content `neverchangeA` before them and an `h1` tag with the content `neverchangeB` after them:

```xml
//span[preceding::h1="neverchangeA" and following::h1="neverchangeB"]
```

To use an XPath expression within puppeteer, use [`page.$x`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.0.1/docs/api.md#pagexexpression).

**Code Sample**

```js
const spans = await page.$x('//span[preceding::h1="neverchangeA" and following::h1="neverchangeB"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **regex**. This: `<h1>.*<h1>` will select the h1 tag and whatever there is between the tag. One way is to remove the result of this from the text, and you will have the result you need.

Comment: do we have built in to puppeteer or plain JavaScript regex

Comment: Assuming you modify the regex with a capturing group, the group will contain a lot more characters than what the OP wants.